# Determine the joint pdf from the conditional distribution and marginal distribution of one of the variables

Tags: calculus, probability, uniform-distribution, density-function

Have this question I think I'm doing right, but I am unsure:

> Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector characterized as follows. The marginal density $f_X(x)=2x$ for $0 \le X \le 1$ and the conditional distribution of Y given X=x is uniformly distributed in [0,x]. Find the joint pdf f(x,y) and marginal density $f_Y$.

From this, I took the conditional probability to be
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
for $0 \le y \le x$ and from there calculated
$$
f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)*f_X(x)=\frac{1}{x}*2x=2
$$
I know pdfs can have values greater than 1, but this seems off to me.

For the marginal distribution of y, I know to integrate the pdf over all values of x, so I did this:
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^y 2dx = 2y
$$
for $0 \le y \le 1$. I can't imagine that this is correct. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density looks like this:

[image]

So, the marginal distribution of $Y$ is given by the following integral

$$\int_y^1 2 \ dx=2(1-y)$$

if $0\leq y\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct except for forgetting to indicate the regions where the pdf is zero, for example by noting,
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{0\le y\le x}
$$
then,
$$
f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)*f_X(x)=\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{0\le y\le x}\,\cdot\,2x\mathbf{1}_{0\le x\le 1}=2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{0\le x\le 1}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{0\le y\le x}
$$
As a check, integrate this over all $x,y$ and you will find that it comes out to $1$ as required. The range of integration you used to calculate the marginal $f_Y(y)$ is incorrect.
$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^1f_{XY}(x,y)dx = \int_y^12dx =2(1-y)$$
since the pdf is zero for $x<y$.